# Telegram-бот с одновременной работой нескольких пользователей

Tags: python

Всем привет, я написал первого в своей жизни бота, который принимает от юзера логин, пароль и еще некоторые данные, авторизируется на сайте и проводит там некоторые операции. Вроде ничего сложного даже для меня у которого опыта в программировании всего 3 месяца ))) Если ботом пользуется один юзер от начала и до конца, то бот работает как часики и все отрабатывает как надо. Но если во время того как бот все еще не закончил работу для одного юзера, им уже начинают пользоваться несколько юзеров, у меня возникают проблемы, глобальные переменные путаются, бот не знает что ему делать и куда тыкать.

Скажите, в каком направлении копать? Асинхронность и потоки? =( либо есть панацея?

```
import telebot
from telebot.types import Message
from telebot import types
import requests


bot = telebot.TeleBot('xxx')


start_text = """
Привет

"""

payment_text = """
Вы можете выбрать один из способов оплаты:
"""

help_text = """
Список команд:
/pushup - запускает процесс
"""

def check_reg(login, password):
    r = requests.post('xxx', data={'login': str(login), 'password': str(password)})
    response = r.text
    return response


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start_handler(message: Message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, start_text)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
def help_handler(message: Message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, help_text)



@bot.message_handler(commands=['up'])
def login_handler(message: Message):
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, a)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_login)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def text_handler(message: Message):
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, b)


def get_login(message: Message):
    if '@' in message.text or '+' in message.text:
        global login
        login = message.text
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, c)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_psw)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, d)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_login)


def get_psw(message):
    global password
    password = message.text
    if check_reg(login, password) == '1':
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, e)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_up)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f)

def get_up(message):
    global up
    up = message.text
    if up.isdigit():
        if int(up) <= 0:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, g)
            bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_up)
        else:
            get_url(message)
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, h)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_up)


def get_url(message):
    keyboard = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    key_xx = types.InlineKeyboardButton("xx", callback_data='xx')
    keyboard.add(key_xx)
    key_yy = types.InlineKeyboardButton("yy", callback_data='yy')
    keyboard.add(key_yy)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text=i, reply_markup=keyboard)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    global url
    if call.data == "xx":
        url = "xx"
        test(call)
    elif call.data == "yy":
        url = "yy"
        test(call)


def test(message):
    test= test()
    if test.login(url, login, password):
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, j)
        if test.auto_click(up):
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, k)
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, n)
            test.kill_task()
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, l)
            test.kill_task()
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, m)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, get_login)
        test.kill_task()

bot.polling(timeout=90)
```

Comment: @Tahir, расскажи подробнее, пожалуйста, как ты решил проблему с тем, что при одновременном использовании бот путает какой пользователь что ввёл. Спасибо

Comment: попробуйте добавить туда БД и использовать данные без переменных, тоесть на прямую из БД

Comment: Совет: можно воспользоваться библиотекой `aiogram` в частности FSM. Почитайте на досуге, будет интересно

Comment: @Ovsenka согласен, я в итоге на него и перешел, там все это работает из под коробки

Answer (score 0):

сделал своими руками

```
user = {}

class user_pojo():
    login = ''
    password = ''
    up = ''

def __init__(self, login, password, up):
    self.login = login
    self.password = password
    self.up = up

def set_login(self, login):
    self.login = login

def set_password(self, password):
    self.password = password

def set_up(self, up):
    self.up = up
```